# Need html code to print webpage image only, in focus

Tags: javascript, html, image, focus

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Coupon Page</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function printCoupon() {
            var timeout = 1000;

            self.focus();
            window.print();
            setTimeout("self.close()", timeout);;
            self.focus();
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body onload="printCoupon();">

    <p><img src="https://nebula.phx3.secureserver.net/2247f0de910e14f95483f60fdae499a0?
    AccessKeyId=8BBF3308EC59517C0B34&disposition=0&alloworigin=1" originalattribute="src" originalpath="coupon.jpg" width="585" height="250">
    </p>

</body>

</html>
```

I've searched for html coding to print webpage image only when image (w585 w250), actual size of image, or a related button is clicked. I found coding that works perfectly yet prints my image really out of focus. The coding you show addresses this by stating focus and such, I've worked on this for near a month without success, Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can try media queries in css to print the image.

Answer (score 0):

Check `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` and compare with image `width` and `height` so if they match then `print` page.

```js
function printCoupon() {
  var timeout = 1000;

  var naturalWidth = $('#img')[0].naturalWidth;
  var naturalHeight = $('#img')[0].naturalHeight;

  var width = $('#img').width()
  var height = $('#img').height();

  if (naturalWidth == width && naturalHeight == height) {

    self.focus();
    window.print();
    setTimeout("self.close()", timeout);;
    self.focus();
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body onload="printCoupon();">

  <p><img id="img" src="https://nebula.phx3.secureserver.net/2247f0de910e14f95483f60fdae499a0?
AccessKeyId=8BBF3308EC59517C0B34&disposition=0&alloworigin=1" originalattribute="src" originalpath="coupon.jpg" width="585" height="250">
  </p>
```